Unexpected behavior for Stripe recurring contribution payments
CiviCRM 5.70.2 on WordPress (6.5.2).
Using the Stripe payment processor for contributions. The recurring payment schedule seems a bit … off. My specific was was supposed to be at 1200 today 4/29/2024. Recurring payments started 4/29/2023 0847. Stripe tells me the payment processed at 0947 today 4/29/2024 (and I got charged, can see the transaction on my credit card). But CiviCRM, over an hour later so far, has not recorded the payment at all.
Is this expected behavior? Will I have to disable recurring contributions again and manually record this payment to get my account in working order?
Thanks for any insight here.
Michael

Is it just the one contribution or all of them? Do you have webhooks configured (see administer - administration console - system status)? https://docs.civicrm.org/stripe/en/latest/webhook/

Non-recurring contributions work fine. Stripe shows no errors and shows the web hooks as active. Curiously, the Administer->CiviContribute->Payment processor web hooks currently shows nothing. I seem to recall an error message before when the web hooks weren’t there a year or so ago, offering to create them. No indication like that now. We have very few recurring donations, and that functionality was enabled barely a year ago (and I was one of the test accounts) because it used to just throw errors on the contribution attempt.

If you look in the stripe portal, under developer (it's a bit of a disguised "button" at the top of the dashboard), there's a tab for webhooks. If you click on the webhook it will give you some logs. Note especially in the right-hand sidebar what it says was the return message was.

Yeah, Stripe says everything worked. The specific requests there all got a 200 response according to Stripe. I can even see the requests in the web server logs and confirm the response. CiviCRM just didn’t process anything. Guess I’ll have to manually record the response and hope that renews my membership, and maybe do an upgrade this weekend to the latest ‘n greatest.

And in the right sidebar for the webhook response at stripe, does it say anything like "this is not for this processor"? Civi will just silently drop those if for some reason it thinks it's not for it (like a mismatch between test and live).

Wouldn’t that be indicated by a request not working? Every single request is successful with HTTP 200 response, no response body, no errors at all. One thing that’s weird is I’m seeing some transactions (related to me removing test accounts) going to the WooCommerce Stripe endpoint URL, so clearly something is confused here. Not seeing the web hooks showing up in CiviCRM’s UI concerns me and is probably why nothing is getting recorded even though requests are not generating errors.
